# Progress Check while running a loop with multiprocessing pool.apply.async

Tags: python, progress-bar, python-multiprocessing

I have dig through everywhere but now I am stuck, and i need the help of the community. I am not a programmer and barely use python inside a VFX program called Houdini.

Using multiprocessing I am running wedges of tasks in batches using another program called hython.

Task creates n amount of folders and populates these folders with x amount of files each with equally total amount of files such as

/files/wedge_1/file1...file2
/files/wedge_2/file1...file2

pool decides how many it can ran these tasks in batches. I am trying to implement a progress bar that runs along the side of my code and checks the files every x amount until total number of files  = total number of files required.

Other possible option is that hython task already can output an alfred progress report, but since everything runs in together i get several copies of same frame printed in terminal, which doesn't tel me from which loop they are coming from.

here is the code for your considerations.

```py
# Importing all needed modules
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import time, timeit
import os

#My Variables
hou.hipFile.load("/home/tricecold/pythonTest/HoudiniWedger/HoudiniWedger.hiplc") #scene file
wedger =   hou.parm('/obj/geo1/popnet/source_first_input/seed') #wedged parameter
cache = hou.node('/out/cacheme') #runs this node
total_tasks = 10 #Wedge Amount
max_number_processes = 5 #Batch Size
FileRange =  abs(hou.evalParmTuple('/out/cacheme/f')[0] - hou.evalParmTuple('/out/cacheme/f')[1])
target_dir = os.path.dirname(hou.evalParm('/out/cacheme/sopoutput')) + "/"
totals = FileRange * total_tasks

def cacheHoudini(wedge=total_tasks): #houdini task definiton
wedger.set(wedge)
time.sleep(0.1)
cache.render(verbose=False)

def files(wedge=total_tasks): #figure out remaining files
    count = 0
    while (count < totals):
        num = len([name for name in os.listdir(target_dir)])
        count = count + 1
        print (count)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(max_number_processes) #define pool size
    #do i need to run my progress function files here  
    for wedge in range(0,total_tasks):
        #or I add function files here, not really sure
        pool.apply_async(cacheHoudini,args=(wedge,)) #run tasks

    pool.close() # After all threads started we close the pool
    pool.join() # And wait until all threads are done
```

Comment: Thanks for including your code - but could you be a bit more specific about exactly what you want help with?

Comment: Sorry , first timer here, I taught i was clear. This code launches several tasks under different PID, each one of them writes out some files under the structure i mentioned above. I want to be able to create a progress bar for each on of these folders and a master progress bar.
That is why I tried to create a while loop under function "files", but i cannot seem to get it working , I am not sure how to launch this as it is a different type of task then the cacheHoudini function